# IIS 7 smtp cant send email

Tags: iis-7, smtp

my application needs to send out emails to its users, but somehow I can't make it work. I have  installed the SMTP server and in IIS I have set SMTP to use localhost, with port 25 without authentication. But when I try to send email, I am allways getting error

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:25
```

When I choose the  option to store email in directory, it works fine, so the problem isn't in my app. Why does this happen? The only thing I am thinking about, is if I need to have port 25 opened or not?

Answer (score 0):

This would happen if you don't have an SMTP server listening on port 25.

Comment: And how should I test it? I don't have full permission on the server so I don't want to bother the admin with something which wont work

Comment: I know this is old but if anyone needs to test this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/153119/xfor-telnet-to-port-25-to-test-smtp-communication